# How to await LINQ query with multiple from clauses?

Tags: c#, async-await, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have the following LINQ query that uses multiple from clauses:

```
var count = (
    from uTask in db.Table<UTask>().Where(u => u.ParentId == componentId && u.RouteId == routeId)
    from workItem in db.Table<WorkItem>().Where(w => w.ParentId == uTask.Id)
    from visualInspectionQuestion in db.Table<VisualInspectionQuestion>().Where(v => v.ParentId == workItem.Id && v.Answer != null)
    select new { }).Count();
```

How can I adjust this so that each of the from clauses are awaited? I'm aware that there a numerous examples of how to use await with LINQ, but I cant find an example of how to handle multiple from clauses. I'm using SQLite-net with the async extensions.

edit 1: I tried the following, as per Evk's suggestion:

```
count = await (
    from uTask in db.Table<UTask>().Where(u => u.ParentId == componentId && u.RouteId == routeId)
    from workItem in db.Table<WorkItem>().Where(w => w.ParentId == uTask.Id)
    from visualInspectionQuestion in db.Table<VisualInspectionQuestion>().Where(v => v.ParentId == workItem.Id && v.Answer != null)
    select new { }).CountAsync();
```

However, this produces the following compiler error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'AsyncTableQuery'. 'SelectMany' not found.

Comment: Just do `await (......).CountAsync()`. Number of from clauses doesn't matter for that.

Comment: @Marc - I want to await all three db.Table calls.

Comment: There should not be 3 db calls. It should be converted to one sql query.

Comment: @Evk - I tried your suggestion (see my edit), but get a compiler error. Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: convert to sql query and use join

Comment: Well I'm not aware of ORM\provider you are using. If that were Entity Framework for example - `CountAsync` should work. Here you are using some `CountAsAsync` which I didn't met before. Maybe someone with more knowledge of this provider can help.

Comment: If you use `await`, you must mark your method with `async`, [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: l see no reason why the first query should compile and the second not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Task.WhenAll()**. This will wait for all your tasks to finish before counting:

```
var tasks = foos.Select(DoSomethingAsync).ToList();
var count = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).CountAsync();
```

Comment: why `.ToList();`?

Comment: To get a list of Tasks out of it in my example.

Comment: I don't think this will work for my example, as the 2nd and 3rd db.Table calls require data from the preceding from clauses.